# AngularJS $state.go is not redirecting to other page

Tags: angularjs, state.go

Below is my controller code,

```
app.controller('logoutCtrl', ['$scope', '$http','$window','$state',
  function ($scope, $http,$window,$state) {

        $scope.logout = function() {
          console.log('inside logmeout');
          delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
          $state.go('access.login');
        };

  }]);
```

HTML

```
<li class="last" ng-controller="logoutCtrl">
    <a href="" ng-click="logout()">
         <i class="material-icons">lock</i> Logout
    </a>
</li>
```

app.router.js

```
            .state('access', {
                url: '/access',
                template: '<div ui-view class=""></div>'
            })
            .state('access.login', {
                url: '/login',
                templateUrl: 'partials/ui-login.html',
                controller: 'LoginFormController',
                resolve: {
                    deps: ['uiLoad',
                        function(uiLoad) {
                            return uiLoad.load(['scripts/controllers/login.js',
                                '../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css']);
                        }
                    ]
                }
            })
```

When clicking the logout i am not able to redirect to another state('access.login'). 
The control is coming inside the logout() and able to print the console message and is deleting the token as well but redirect not happening..
Can i get any help..

Comment: Show the `state` defination inside your routes!

Comment: post the config

Comment: @RNS: Show us route configuration

Comment: @RNS: Review  your state: access.login consider access as parent state and login as child state. either try to define access as parent state and then create child state acecss.login or put only login as statename

Comment: do you have a run block where you are checking for $stateChangeStart?

Comment: @RNS: Scotch.io website is really very helpful to understand nested state concepts. access.login treat as nested state So please either define parent state and then use it like or put just login as state.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router

Comment: i have defined parent state like this                                            .state('access', {
                        url: '/access',
                        template: '<div ui-view class=""></div>'
                    })

Comment: @PawanGupta no am not doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your module definition you need to pass 'ui.router' as a dependency in order to use the Angular-UI-Router in your project:

E.g. angular.module('my_app', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])

It works for me as well.

> $state.go('the-state-name-in-quotes')

Answer (score 0):

If your web page is displayed within a view, don't forget to include ui-view in the parent page where you want to display the web page.

```
<div ui-view>
  <!-- Child page will appear here -->
</div>
```